# In order for Sound to exist, are Spacetime, Matter & Motion required first, in that exact order?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, spacetime, acoustics, matter

From what I’ve read so far online, briefly reading Newton, Einstein, and Minkowski’s theories this is the order I’ve come to. I.e, for matter to exist first there has to be space and time, for motion to exist there has to be space, time & matter, and for sound to exist there has to be space, time, matter (air) and motion.

Order of existence:

1. Space & Time
2. Matter
3. Motion
4. Sound

I’m new to studying physics. I am coming from a musical background so please bear with me. I just recently tried to ask if motion has to exist before time, now I’m wondering if it is actually the other way around. Space and Time have to exist as a dimension (domain) for matter, and then motion to exist correct?

If I’m doing something wrong can someone please edit the question for me, or tell me how to fix it before just closing it.

Comment: If you are interested in the big ideas like these, you might be interested in Sean Carroll's [The Biggest Ideas in the Universe!](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrxfgDEc2NxZJcWcrxH3jyjUUrJlnoyzX). This is a series of lectures for the general public. Early lectures start off with simple ideas like space. Later lectures get into advanced topics.

Comment: Spacetime is one thing, not two separate things. Motion is automatically provided once you have that. Material is needed for sound, so you just need spacetime and materials. However, think about what experimental observations would be needed to figure out which came first; and does it even matter which ordering of creation? Why not the opposite ordering? Why not both happening together? What particular problem are you facing that requires the ordering to be specified?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent oh I thought space was 3d and time was 1d and then added together or something like that. The reason I’m interested in the order is sort of non physics related. I’m theorizing about the importance of time in the creation of sound (pitch) and in the creation of music.

Comment: We used to think space and time are different things. Einstein and Minkowski showed us that only spacetime together is one coherent whole. Viewing them as separate will necessarily cause trouble. Now, there is absolutely no need to theorise about sound, pitch, music, because all of these are now completely understood in normal (quantum) physics.

Comment: When asking questions about existence, you need to be careful how you define it. Space & time are not material entities and arguably do not exist except as ways to keep track of things that do.

Comment: @D.Halsey So are there different concepts of time because what I’m essentially trying to understand is the construction of sound. Since sound is defined by frequency, which is cycles per second. This implies that we need space, time, matter, & motion to create it. I’m just curious if there is an order to the creation of those elements.